# What does "an isometry is not the restriction of an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$" mean? How to show that?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

I'm dealing with a problem associated with helicoid-and-catenoid isometry.
Paramatrize helicid by $f_{1}=(u\cos v,u\sin v,v)$, catenoid by $f_{2}=(\cosh z \cos\theta,\cosh z\sin\theta,z)$. Let $u=\sinh z$ and $v=\theta $, their first fundamental form become the same \begin{pmatrix}
\cosh^{2}z &0 \\ 
0 & \cosh^{2}
\end{pmatrix}

However, I don't understand what's "this isometry is not the restriction of an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$" mean and don't know how to show this.

Comment: MathJax tip: to stop the letters in your trig functions from running together, try using the trig function commands `\cos, \sin, \cosh`. For example, `$\cosh z \cos \theta$` produces $\cosh z \cos \theta$, which looks *much* clearer than `$cosh z cos \theta$`, which produces $cosh z cos \theta$.

Comment: This means that this application is not the restriction of an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other word, this isometry of the catenoid cannot be extended to the whole ambiant space as an euclidean isometry.

Comment: OK... how to show this rigorously? Is it because in the coordinate transformation I used, $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ but $v\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: To show this rigorously, take any isometry of the euclidean space. It is a composition of a rotation, a reflexion and/or a translation. Show that it does not restrict to a transformation of the form you gave in your question.